# Definition of a simple group in terms of logical notation

Tags: group-theory

The definition of a simple group is as follows:

A non-trivial group $G$ is called a simple group if $\left\{1\right\}$ and $G$ are the only normal subgroups of $G$.

I would like to know if my modification is also logically equivalent:

A non-trivial group $G$ is called a simple group if (there exists $H \trianglelefteq G$) implies ($H=\left\{1\right\}$ or $G$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote it, what you said isn't syntactically valid. When you say $(\exists H\subseteq G)(H\trianglelefteq G)$, $H$ can't appear outside of that expression. What you want to say is
$$(\forall H\subseteq G)(H\trianglelefteq G \implies (H = \{1\} \, \lor\, H = G))$$

Comment: Thank you so much, do you think if it will still make sense if I changed the last "or" to "and"?

Comment: Syntax may allow that usage, though standard notation/definition would render it invalid. Yet, the formula is clear and correct if we don't care about syntax (and I don't.)

Comment: If $G$ is nontrivial, then it's impossible to have $H = \{1\}$ and $H = G$.

Comment: @florence Thank you so much, it makes sense why we can't use "and" clearly. The only reason that I wasn't 100% comfortable with "or" was that there could be ,for instance, a non-trivial group of which trivial subgroup is normal but the group itself is not normal (I am aware that there does not exist such a group but I am saying this from a purely logical perspective), which would render our definition wrong.

Comment: If that were possible, it still wouldn't create problems for what I wrote. A group is normal provided that any normal subgroup is either $\{1\}$ or $G$. Even if it did turn out there are no normal subgroups equal to $G$, that doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @florence Thank you so much. True, it wouldn't create problems for what you wrote as $G$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$ in the first place, but don't you think if we use the original definition then $G$ is not simple as $G$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$? I am a bit confused as my logic is not that strong :(

Comment: What if I changed the last part to (for every $H$)($H$ is {1} or $G$ $\iff$ $H$ is normal in $G$)?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I feel like the second definition better captures what a simple group is, and we can only appeal to the first definition since it's trivial that $\{1\}$ and $G$ are normal subgroups of $G$. However, assume that we treat the first definition as more fundamental. Now if you don't want to use this theorem, then you would have to take the second definition and tack on $\land \, \{1\}\trianglelefteq G \, \land \, G \trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: And what you just wrote is also good.

Comment: @florence Oh I see what you meant. Thank you so much for the enlightenment.